# How do I change colour of the code in jekyll 3.3

Tags: jekyll

So I got Jekyll 3.3.1 and everything is different like the location of folders and other stuff. I googled how to change colour of the code in jekyll posts but cannot find any step by step results. I am trying to achieve sublime text theme!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Rouge for highlighting? If so, have a look at [this](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/issues/343) discussion on github.com.

You have to modify the Css file for the language(s) you want to support and then add the file to your page